# About one SQLite ANR: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have met an anr when my app running, the main part of the anr is as following

```
> "Binder_4" prio=5 tid=25 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424c6388 self=0x663bc6b8
  | sysTid=25755 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1715191264
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=2 core=3
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x424c63e0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=25 (Binder_4)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:670)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:586)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1563)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
  at com.xxx.xxx.db.VideoProvider.update(VideoProvider.java:76)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:235)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1036)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.db.DBTask.update(DBTask.java:217)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.db.TaskDBManager.updateTask(TaskDBManager.java:74)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.task.BigSiteTask.setState(BigSiteTask.java:734)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.task.BigSiteTask.pause(BigSiteTask.java:536)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.task.TaskManager.stop(TaskManager.java:695)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.DownloadInterfaceStub.stop(DownloadInterfaceStub.java:67)
  at com.xxx.xxx.download.DownloadInterface$Stub.onTransact(DownloadInterface.java:89)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The "*waiting on <0x424c63e0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=25 (Binder_4)*" is a little strange because it seems the Binder_4 thread (with tid=25) block itself, am I right? I just don't know why this happens. One thread causes itself running into dead lock?

Comment: You got the solution for this